# Excel Find the Column # When a Value Exceeds a Threshold

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am in need of three complementary Excel formulas.

1. The first needs to return the first column number when a specific threshold is exceeded by 5 (Threshold Reached Col #)
2. The second formula needs to return the count of columns starting from the column the threshold was reached (Count Since Thresh Reached)
3. The third formula needs to count how many columns did not reach the threshold starting from when the threshold was reached (Count Below Thresh)

| Col Num | Threshold | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 | Thresh Reached Col # | Count Since Thresh Reached | Count Below Thresh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 15 | 5 | 25 | 30 | 35 | Col 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 15 | 10 | 20 | 25 | 0 | Col 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 75 | 75 | 90 | 100 | 75 | 30 | Col 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 55 | 50 | 40 | 35 | 80 | 80 | Col 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 100 | 101 | 95 | 80 | 100 | 104 | Thresh Not Reached | 0 | "" |

Comment: Try using `MATCH` and `INDEX` and `COUNTIFS`? Did you make at least any attempt here?

Comment: match() for exceeding the value, then match() - x if table does not start in A. then match(result) - 1 will give the number of cols not reaching threshold.

Comment: Yes. The below is only giving me the count of values until the threshold is reached. I do not know how to pull the actual column name from here instead of the count (range of reference from C2 to S2.

=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C7:S7>B7,),0),"Threshold Not Exceeded")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the column header, try the following formula...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$6:$S$6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C7:S7>B7,),0)),"Threshold Not Exceeded")
```